# Postman - Convert an ISO format date into a UNIX timestamp

Tags: postman

I’m trying to convert a ISO timestamp into a UNIX timestamp to test this converted value with the current value.

The date is `2018-02-15T00:33:02.000Z`

Can this be converted into a UNIX timestamp within Postman?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’ve provided an answer but the question is very poor - you need to add more detail and context, to get a better answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert this time in Postman using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) which comes with the native application.

```
var moment = require("moment")

console.log(moment("2018-02-15T00:33:02.000Z").valueOf())
```

This would convert the value and print it on the Postman Console if you add this to the `pre-request script` or `Tests` tab.

This is always a good site for cross checking: http://currentmillis.com/

The same could be done in native JavaScript but moment makes it much easier.

The question is very vague as to what you are trying to do but this is a basic answer.

Comment: I Find the Solution by use  this Javaiscript methode  Date.parse https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Comment: Yep, that’s the other native JavaScript way that I mentioned - I would personally lean more towards using `moment` as it’s a much easier and more powerful API for all things time and date. It also comes with the Postman application so it’s ready to use in your scripts.